# how to make our appointment section responsive in mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

am stuck with a problem, I made a appointment page , it is properly working on desktop mode but when am trying to see in mobile view it is not responsive , can anyone help me to fix this error

> Appointment.js

This is the appointment page where I wrote my all code, I want its working on mobile view properly
[image: error imag]

```
import React from 'react';
import './Appoinment.css';

const Appoinment = () => {
    return (
        <div className="backimg">
            <div className="container mt-5 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white shadow-lg p-3"  >
                <h2>Book Appoinment</h2><br/>
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label className="label" for="inputEmail4">Patient Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label className="label" for="inputEmail4">Doctor's Name</label>
                            <select name="select" class="form-control shadow-none">
                                <option selected>Doctor Name1</option>
                                <option selected>Doctor Name2</option>
                                <option selected>Doctor Name3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label className="label" for="inputEmail4">Department's Name</label>
                            <select name="select" class="form-control shadow-none">
                                <option selected>Cardiology</option>
                                <option>Diagnosis</option>
                                <option>Surgery</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div><br /><br /><br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label  className="label"for="inputEmail4">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label className="label" for="inputEmail4">Symptoms</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label className="label" for="inputEmail4">Choose Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control shadow-none"  />
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit Now</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Appoinment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the className **col** on the columns with className="col-md-4 col-12"

At small devices the columns will be full width and above ≥768px it will have 1/3.

edit:
Also make the class="" to className